# pip install pacakge with an error "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError" occurred

Tags: python

When I installed the ansible module in Pycharm, the following error occurred：

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\22946\\AppDat
a\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-owwfux38\\ansible_bf2fa499f2d34802a4db896d6c1f85bc\\ansible_collections/amazon/aws/tests/unit/mo
dules/placebo_recordings/aws_direct_connect_connection/associations_are_not_updated/directconnect.DescribeConnections_1.json
'
```

The software version is as follows：

- **python**: Python 3.8.5

Please help me with this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Windows has a maximum path length of 260 characters. That's why it's throwing error.
Solution:
Install the package in a folder which has shorter path.
To help you remove max path error. Follow the link provided.
[Follow link](https://docs.python.org/3.7/using/windows.html)

Comment: You can remove the limit(by opening python installer, there is a option to remove the limit)